# How to write method in exclamation way, modified on itself not returns the modified copy

Tags: ruby

I want to make the change on the original string object, how to ?

Now, it only returns the copy.

```
class String
  def clean_text!
    self.delete("\n").gsub!(/\s/,'')
  end
  def add_sig!
    self + "add sig"
  end
end
```

Comment: Your title and the question do not match. The question is unclear because of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.delete!("\n")
self.gsub!(/\s/,'')
self
```

Also, newlines are already included in `\s` so no need to have `self.delete!("\n")`. Simply do

```
class String
  def clean_text!
    self.gsub!(/\s/,'')
    self
  end
end
```

For `add_sig`, use `<<` instead of `+`:

```
  def add_sig!
    self << "add sig"
  end
```

Comment: Hi I updated it , how to finish it in `add_sig ` method ? thanks so much

Comment: `clean_text!` would be a bit cleaner like this: `def clean_text!; tap { |s| s.gsub!(/\s/, '') }; end`

Comment: @AlexD Why the need to use `tap`? I disagree. It makes it less efficient.

Comment: @konsolebox, it's a way to make "bang" methods which don't return `self` chainable. When you get used to using it as such, seeing `tap` instantly says to you: "mutating and then returning self". Of course, tastes vary.